# Arrays associativos

Tags: php

Galera trabalho faz um tempo como designer/front-end, mas só agora estou estudando php e estou com uma dúvida.

Preciso criar um array associativo com 20 alunos contendo: matricula, nome e altura. E mostrar os 5 alunos mais altos da turma, mostrando somente a matricula do aluno e a altura.

Qual a melhor maneira de realizar esse exercício?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a função [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), para ordenar o array, a função auxiliar `cmp` define qual será o critério da ordenação e for exibe apenas os cinco alunos mais altos.

```
$alunos = [
        ['nome' => "Doge", "matricula" => "M1", "altura" => 1.70 ],
        ['nome' => "João", "matricula" => "M2", "altura" => 1.90 ],
        ['nome' => "Pedro", "matricula" => "M4", "altura" => 1.50 ],
        ['nome' => "Mario", "matricula" => "M3", "altura" => 1.60 ],
        ['nome' => "A1", "matricula" => "M5", "altura" => 1.90 ],
        ['nome' => "A2", "matricula" => "M6", "altura" => 1.88 ]

];

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a["altura"] < $b["altura"];
}


usort($alunos, "cmp");

for($i=0; $i<5;$i++){
    echo $i .': '.  $alunos[$i]['nome'] .' - '.$alunos[$i]['altura'] .'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
0: A1 - 1.9
1: João - 1.9
2: A2 - 1.88
3: Doge - 1.7
4: Mario - 1.6
```

Uma variação da solução seria usa [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) para remover todos itens a partir da quinta posição e usar um foreach.

```
array_splice($alunos, 5);

foreach($alunos as $item){
    echo $item['nome'] .' - '. $item['altura'] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resposta muito valiosa me ajudou muito!!!!

Comment: Muito boa explicação, obrigado mesmo!!!